# Is there anything only supported by Pivotal Query Optimizer?

Tags: greenplum

Is there anybody knows that anything is not supported by Greenplum Legacy Query optimizer, but supported by Pivotal Query Optimizer?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

PQO generate plans that do a better job with partition elimination, and optimizing query common table expressions (WITH Clause). As far SQL support is concerned, Legacy Query Optimizer handles all SQL that GPDB supports. If PQO sees an operation that it does not support, it automatically falls to planner.